# How can I split a string of Numbers and multiply the separate numbers?

Tags: c++, string, split, delimiter

I have two separate numbers in a string. I figured out how to split the string with a delimiter (output being 136) but am stuck with how I can multiply the two numbers and store the result in a variable. Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()

{
    std::string b = "13,6";
    std::string delimiter = ",";
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;

    while ((pos = b.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = b.substr(0, pos);
        std::cout << token;
        
        b.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }

    std::cout << b;

}
```

Comment: And how would you multiply two numbers, were they not written in a string?

Comment: There are functions in the std lib for conversion from string. Google it.

Comment: You can split your elephant into three bites: 1. split the string on the delimiter, 2. convert the individual strings into integers, 3. multiply the integers. You look like you have #1. But you're trying to go to #3 without having done #2 first. Look at the [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)  or [`std:stol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family of functions.With preference on the latter as "more C++-like"

Comment: @bipll: Yes, they were written in a string... Will try the conversion. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks to you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()

{
    std::string b = "13,6";
    std::string delimiter = ",";
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    int number1;
    int number2;

    while ((pos = b.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = b.substr(0, pos);
        number1 = std::stoi(token);

        b.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
    number2 = std::stoi(b);
    std::cout << number1*number2;

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop if there are exactly 2 numbers?

Comment: True. This was just an example. The actual input were two strings containing two numbers each.